# How to show user the URL once image uploaded

Tags: php, forms, upload

I am looking for a way where when a user uploads a image in PHP it shows them the URL to the file.

My current `upload.php` is the following:

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
 
 //database configuration
 $dbHost = 'localhost';
 $dbUsername = 'root';
 $dbPassword = '';
 $dbName = 'codexworld';
 //connect with the database
 $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
 if($mysqli->connect_errno){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
 }
 
 $targetDir = "http://wotm8.net/";
 $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
  //insert file information into db table
  $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
 }
 
}
?>
```

Ignore the database. I don't use that
if you need the index file or anything else then ask.

---

HTML PAGE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030"> 
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="_wLD3KO_vuO5czv-n-j9YrXxO3OtQuGc6C51vOaRHMU" />
    <title>wotm8.net 路 File Hosting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropzone.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 id="logo">wotm8.net</h1>
        <p class="lead">Max upload size is 75MiB, read the <a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></p>
            <noscript>
                <p class="alert alert-error"><strong>Enable JavaScript</strong> you autist neckbeard, it's not gonna hurt you</p>
            </noscript>
            <p id="no-file-api" class="alert alert-error"><strong>Your browser is shit.</strong> Install the latest<a href="http://firefox.com/">Firefox</a> or <a href="http://chrome.google.com/">Botnet</a> and come back &lt;3</p>
 <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" data-max-size="75MiB">
   
</div>
    </form>
            <ul id="upload-filelist"></ul>
     <audio id="sickerMeme" src="meme.mp3" />
     <script>
  var i = 0, text;
  var str = "Dude, that's a sick meme.";
  function start(){
//   document.getElementById("sickerMeme").play();type();
  }
  /* Credits: https://jsfiddle.net/creed88/VG8MJ/1/ */

  function type(){
   text = str.slice(0, ++i);
   if (text === str) return;
   document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML = text;
   setTimeout(type, 80);
  }
     </script>
        </div>
 <!-- Leo5gg lol -->
         <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="//www.wotm8.net">Index</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
        </nav>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to show the user the URL to what they uploaded. For example If example.com was a image uploader, and I upload a image It will show the user something on the screen like example.com/test.jpeg that they can click and go to

Comment: you have to put an anchorage reference in html view:

Comment: so u u want to echo $targetDir = "http://wotm8.net/your file name" right?

Comment: is file upload okay?is it upload to folder?

Comment: Your target dir should be a absolute path, not a website link, should be something like /var/www/folder/

Answer (score 0):

I think your upload directory is $targetFile

You can echo it out or return it in any way you think is safe

Like after insert into database

```
echo $targetFile;
```

Comment: I dont know why but whenever I add code it to it it responds with an error.

Comment: Show your html page or where you want it to display

Comment: added html to post

Comment: Is the html on the same page i.e is the page file name upload.php

Comment: If the upload is successful, you can query your database to get list of uploaded files and get their directory name on the page you want it to display.

Comment: for uploading try this [link]https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Answer (score -1):

EDIT

Your target dir should be a absolute path, not a website link, should be something like /var/www/folder/

I doubt your upload is working in the example you posted.

after you manage to make the upload successful, just echo your domain + relative folder ( if any) + filename.

Comment: He wants to put a link in html not `echo` or `var_dump`.

Comment: When I use that it says Server Responded with 500 Code. and it doesn't show a link